# How to create an ASP.NET Core MVC boilerplate from a custom base project

Tags: c#, templates, asp.net-core-mvc, aspnetboilerplate

Like a lot of developers, I often create new projects with the same features (Authentication, IoC, tests etc..).

#### What I want to do?

I would like to be able to create a new project based on a custom template code project.

#### What kind of project?

Currently I'm creating a lot of new in ASP.NET Core MVC projects.
My goal is to generate those new project from a specific template (with some configuration options like the project name).

It's possible in the JavaScript world (with some command lines like `expo init my-react-native-project`). So is it possible to do it for ASP.NET Core MVC projects?

I hope what I want to do is correctly explained :)
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom template from an existing project by adding a .template.configtemplate.json file

Essentially, you can setup the project to have all of the common functionality you required i.e. Authentication, test, IOC and re-use this in a new project.

Have a look at this post for futher details:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/how-to-create-your-own-templates-for-dotnet-new/

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's exactly what I was looking for! It works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates?view=vs-2019

This topic shows you how to create a template using the Export Template Wizard, which packages your template in a .zip file.

Use the Export Template Wizard
Create a project.

Note

Use only valid identifier characters when naming a project that will be the source for a template. Otherwise, compilation errors can occur in projects that are created from the template. For more information about valid identifier characters, see Declared element names (Visual Basic) or Identifiers (C++). Alternatively, you can use Template parameters to use "safe" names for classes and namespaces.

Edit the project until it is ready to be exported as a template. For example, you might want to edit code files to indicate where parameter replacement should take place. See How to: Substitute parameters in a template.

On the Project menu, choose Export Template.

The Export Template Wizard opens.

On the Choose Template Type page, select Project Template. Select the project you want to export to a template, and then choose Next.

On the Select Template Options page, enter a name and optional description, icon, and preview image for your template. These items will appear in the dialog box where you create a new project. Choose Finish.

The project is exported into a .zip file and placed in the specified output location, and, if selected, imported into Visual Studio.

To find your template in the dialog box where you create a new project, search for it by name or scroll through the list. (Filtering based on language or project type is not currently possible for user templates.)

Other ways to create project templates
You can create project templates manually by gathering the files that constitute the project into a folder and creating a .vstemplate XML file with the appropriate metadata. For more information, see How to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-manually-create-web-templates?view=vs-2019

If you have the Visual Studio SDK installed, you can wrap the finished template in a VSIX file for deployment by using the VSIX Project template. For more information, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/getting-started-with-the-vsix-project-template?view=vs-2019.

Comment: I already tried by following this documentation and maybe I did something wrong. That's why I post a question here... Maybe I was not clear enough in the wording of it.